# If $k \neq i \Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj}A_{ij}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The $(i,j)$ cofactor $A_{ij}$ is defined in terms of the minor by $A_{ij} = (-1)^{i+j}\det(M_{ij})$

*Corollary*. If $k \neq i \Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj}A_{ij}=0$.

Now proof in my lecture notes is this. Let's $A$ be matrix such that $\forall j[a_{ij} = a_{kj}] $

Then $\det A = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}A_{ij}= \sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj}A_{ij}$ from here $\Rightarrow$ $\det A=0$.

Now my question is what if $A$ is not a matrix such that  $\forall j[a_{ij} = a_{kj}] $? If this doesn't hold for this $A$ than how  corollary is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the author means is this: copy the elements of $A$ to a new matrix $B$. Then, replace the $i$-row of $B$ by the $k$-th row of $A$. Now we have $b_{ij}=a_{kj}$ (because the $i$-th row of $B$ is the $k$-row of $A$) and $B_{ij}=A_{ij}$ (because $A$ and $B$ differ only in the $i$-rows). Therefore, by Laplace expansion along the $i$-th row,
$$
\det(B)=\sum_{j=1}^nb_{ij}B_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^na_{kj}A_{ij}.
$$
However, $B$ has two identical rows (both the $i$-th and $k$-th rows of $B$ are equal to the $k$-th row of $A$), $\det(B)$ must be zero. Therefore $\sum_{j=1}^na_{kj}A_{ij}=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!.